# Database not updating correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zendesk

I was hoping you could help me with a problem I've been stuck on for quite a while now. I have a database with tickets. These tickets contain information, like a status. My application uses the Zendesk API to get info from support tickets and store them into my database.

What I want to do is store the previous and current status of a ticket into my database. I am trying to accomplish this by storing the old values before updating my database. At first this seemed to work great. Whenever I change the status in Zendesk, my app changes the previous_state to the old state value and the actual state to the one it gathers from Zendesk.

However, it goes wrong whenever I refresh my page. When that happens (and the method gets called again), for some reason it puts both the previous_state and state on the same value. I must be doing something wrong in one of my update or store lines but I can't figure out what. I hope someone of you can help me out.

Ticket is the Ticket database, client is the zendesk connection. The last loop checks if the status and previous_status are the same and if so, tries to put the previous state back to the previous state before the big update with zendesk. The idea is that the previous state remains unchanged until the actual state changes.

```
previousTickets = Ticket.all

Ticket.all.each do |old|
  old.update(:previous_status => old.status)
end

client.tickets.each do |zt|
  Ticket.find_by(:ticket_id => zt.id).update(
    subject: zt.subject,
    description: zt.description,
    ticket_type: zt.type,
    status: zt.status,
    created: zt.created_at,
    organization_id: zt.organization_id,
    )
end

Ticket.all.each do |newTicket|
  if(newTicket.status == newTicket.previous_status)
    b = previousTickets.find_by(:ticket_id => newTicket.ticket_id)
    c = b.previous_status
    newTicket.update(:previous_status => c)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last loop isn't working because `previousTickets` does not contain previous tickets, but current ones. This is due to the fact that `Ticket.all` returns only an ActiveRecord relation. Such is relation loads data in a lazy way : unless you use the content of the relation, it won't be loaded from the database.

You could explicitly load all tickets by converting the relation to an array:

```
previousTickets = Ticket.all.to_a
```

But I think you could achieve everything in one single loop: instead of populating all `previous_status` in the first loop and reverting it in the last, you should simply change the `previous_status` when you change the current one:

```
client.tickets.each do |zt|
  ticket = Ticket.find_by(:ticket_id => zt.id)
  previous_status = ticket.previous_status
  previous_status = ticket.status if zt.status != ticket.status
  ticket.update(
    subject: zt.subject,
    description: zt.description,
    ticket_type: zt.type,
    previous_status: previous_status,
    status: zt.status,
    created: zt.created_at,
    organization_id: zt.organization_id,
  )
end
```